# Discussion about data modeling of users in mongoldb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, security, backend

My questions is simple: 
IS a good idea separate users model into one model to store password to get access to it and another model only for profile?.
Or have everything together using one model.
What is good if we talk about security.

What do you think ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the way your application works. If only the back-end can access your database, then you'll be fine with storing sensitive information with the profile.

However, if the client side is directly accessing the database, then you should keep the information separate, and only allow clients access to the public profile.